# What I do with this small metal part in my Samsung laptop NP530U4C

Tags: laptop

I was cleaning my laptop, Samsung Seris S Ultra NP530U4C, and after assembling all parts I found this little metal part (pictures below) not assembled, tried to fit it anywhere but couldn't and as everything was fine I just ignored it.

Now, 5 days later, my laptop works fine except for something very strange, WIFI keeps dropping every 2 or 3 minutes, completely drop and nothing opens, tried multiple networks and it's the same thing, my other laptop and mobiles working perfectly on the same networks, tried to re-install windows and still the same issue.

Did I just broke my WIFI or something else? Where should I put this part?

part upside:

[image]

part downside:

[image]

Comment: Have a close look at the pictures in [Disassembling Samsung Laptop Ultrabook NP530U3B - iFixit Repair Guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Disassembling+Samsung+Laptop+Ultrabook+NP530U3B/23322)

Comment: Chances are in cleaning it you've just dislodged the Wifi antenna cable.

Comment: Or you reattached the 2 WiFi cables the wrong way round. See the photo in step 11 in my link above.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidPostill, thanks for the link, I am the one who asked this question, the link you add is for another model and mine is completely different and bottom cover isn't the same, I can't find any image matches the same part I added earlier and still don't know where to fit it...